# Liferay Login Portlet in Popup

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui

we have a liferay theme were they have removed the dockbar.

What I need to do now is to add the "Sign In" functionality like in the standard Liferay 6.2 theme where the login portlet opens in a popup.

How do I open the liferay login portlet in a popup from my theme ?

best regards,

Daniel

Comment: This blog from liferay.com would be good start to achieve what you want https://www.liferay.com/web/pokuri.jayaram/blog/-/blogs/portlet-in-popup-window-in-liferay-6-2

Comment: That´s true ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here´s how to add the login portlet in a popup.

1) Open the main.js file in the welcome-tehem and take a look at this line:

`signIn.plug(Liferay.SignInModal);`

Go ahead, copy the content of the file and put it in your main.js file.

2) Copy the li - Element from the dockbar containing the link to the login portlet and put it in your theme.

That´s it: You have now a link whose content is opened in a popup :)